# How can I have a secondary optional ViewBuilder in a SwiftUI view?

Tags: swift, swiftui, viewbuilder

This is the code that I currently have. Basically I want to have an optional ViewBuilder to add a conditional view, lets say an accessory view. In a kind of `.overlay` syntax, where you can either have or don't have an overlay.
But at the time of inserting the view that I'm getting this error
`Cannot convert value of type '' to closure result type 'Content'`

```swift
public struct MyView<Content: View>: View {

    @State var isHidden: Bool = false
    // stuff here
    let content: (Int) -> Content
    var additionalView: (() -> Content)?
    
    public init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Int) -> Content, additionalView: (() -> Content)? = nil) {
        self.content = content
        self.additionalView = additionalView
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            ZStack {
                content(selection)
            }
            // more stuff
            
            if !isHidden {
                if let additionalView {
                    additionalView()
                }
                // Another view
            }
        }
    }
    
    public func accessoryView(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) -> some View {
        var view = self
        view.additionalView = content
        return view
    }
}
```

Finally I want to call it this way.

```swift
struct MyMainView<Content: View>: View {
    @StateObject var appInfo: AppInfo = AppInfo()
    @ViewBuilder let content: (Int) -> Content

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            MyView(content: content)
                .accessoryView {
                    AnyKindOfView()
                // This is where it fails with "Cannot convert value of type 'AnyKindOfView' to closure result type 'Content'"
                }
                .onAppear {
                    //code
                }
        }
        .environmentObject(appInfo)
    }
}
```

What am I missing here? I have tried to create an additional, <AdditionalContent: View> for it but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should indeed use an extra type parameter to identify the type of the accessory view. The accessory view will not necessarily be the same as `Content` after all. This is how some of the built-in SwiftUI views are designed, like how `Label` has 2 type parameters representing the title and the icon.

```
public struct MyView<Content: View, Accessory: View>: View {
    // ...
    var additionalView: (() -> Accessory)?

    // ...
    public init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Int) -> Content, additionalView: (() -> Accessory)?) {
        // ...
    }
}

extension MyView where Accessory == Never {

    public init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Int) -> Content) {
        self.init(content: content, additionalView: nil)
    }
}
```

Note that the optional parameter makes Swift have a hard time inferring the `Accessory` type, so I removed it, and added a one-parameter `init` in an extension where `Accessory == Never`. Again, this is similar to how SwiftUI's built-in views with optional view builders work. For example, the `Button` initialisers that does not take a `label` view builder are declared in an extension where `Label == Text`.

For the `accessoryView` modifier, it needs to be generic too. It should return a new `MyView`, with a different `Accessory` type parameter.

```
public func accessoryView<NewAccessory: View>(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> NewAccessory) -> some View {
    MyView<Content, NewAccessory>(content: self.content, additionalView: content)
}
```

Though I don't think this is necessary. Why not just pass in the view directly into the initialiser's `additionalView` argument?

---

Another way is to use `AnyView` as the type of the accessory view. This involves making the `init`s generic as well.

```
public struct MyView<Content: View>: View {
    // ...
    var additionalView: (() -> AnyView)?

    public init<Accessory: View>(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Int) -> Content, additionalView: (() -> Accessory)?) {
        self.content = content
        if let additionalView {
            self.additionalView = { AnyView(additionalView()) }
        }
    }

    // ...

    public func accessoryView<Accessory: View>(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Accessory) -> some View {
        var view = self
        view.additionalView = { AnyView(content()) }
        return view
    }
}

extension MyView {

    public init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Int) -> Content) {
        self.init(content: content, additionalView: nil as (() -> Never)?)
    }
}
```